# priority of calbacks, how to handle a xmlhttprequest post request with node express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web

I have a problem with managing xmlhttprequest post request. This is the code of the node express server:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = 3001



app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.use("/", (request, response) => {

  console.log("inside app.use")

  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"))


})

app.post("/database", (request, response) => {

  console.log("inside app.use02")

  console.log("request-body: "+request)

  console.log("response-body: "+response)

  response.send("it works")

})


app.listen(port)
```

The problem is thatwhen i do a ajax request to the /database url, it gets served by the app.use statement instead of the app.post statement. Why is that? is something that I'm no understanding ofhow expressjs works, what is it?

```
const btnForm = document.getElementById("form-btn")
const input01 = document.getElementById("firstName")
const input02 = document.getElementById("lastName")
const input03 = document.getElementById("profession")
const form = document.getElementById("form01")


form.addEventListener("submit", sendForm)


const httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
const FD = new FormData()


function sendForm(event){

  event.preventDefault()


  console.log("sendForm")


  FD.append(input01.name, input01.value)
  FD.append(input02.name, input02.value)
  FD.append(input03.name, input03.value)


  httprequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:3001/database")

  httprequest.send(FD)  

}
```

What I want to know is why the ajax request is served by the app.use statement first instead of the app.post statement, I thought that since I'm doing a ajax post request it should have to get responded with the app.post statement, despise he app.use statement being called before.

Comment: change `app.use("/")` to `app.get("/")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should instead be

```
app.get("/", (request, response) => {

  console.log("inside app.use")

  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"))


})
```

app.get / app.post is to define routes. While, app.use is to attach middleware.

Comment: @mainprogram:  You might want to consider upvoting the right answer so that anyone else browsing this question can easily infer from others answers (if any).